# Insert a UIViewController in an existing UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm developing an app (in Swift with UI builder) where I have a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController so I can present details about the rows, use a standard '+' button to add rows to the table etc. At that point, the UINavigationController is the entry point to the storyboard.

Now I want to add a login screen as a UIViewController before the UITableViewController in the storyboard, so the user needs to log in first and, upon successful authentication, would be taken to the table view. I'm expecting the new view controller should be embedded within the existing navigation controller (makes sense to me for the sake of continuity). However, I can't figure out how I can insert the login screen within the navigation controller without breaking the existing navigation. I've tried several approaches, e.g. creating a new segue from the login screen to the table view, then replacing the relationship "root view controller" between the navigation controller and the table view with a new one with the login screen, but when I do this all the navigation elements in the table view and the subsequent screens (details, data creation) disappear.

Is there a trick to doing this, or will I have to recreate the whole navigation logic?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you intending to navigate from your Login screen to your Table View?

Comment: Don't insert the login screen. Present it from the top view so the user doesn't see the top view until after successfully logging in.

Comment: @DonMag My attempt was to instantiate it using the storyboard in the login screen class, then present it upon pressing a "Login" button and checking for the proper credentials. Doing this, the table view is displayed, but, as I said, the navigation bar at the top of the screen has disappeared above the table view.

Comment: @maddy Is that the standard way to do it? Not quite sure, since I want to also allow the user to e.g. go to an account-creation screen from the login screen, or display user info etc after login and before presenting the table, it feels like the login screen should be a rightful step in the navigation process, which may be skipped after the user has successfully logged in once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're on the right track... not sure where you're going wrong.

This would be (one) valid approach, and *should* give you what you're going for.

**Edit**: Note also, if you are navigating via code, you want to PUSH ViewControllers onto the Navigation stack, not "present" them. E.G.: `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableViewController, animated: true)`

Start with NavController... TableView is Nav's Root, and DetailView is shown on Table Row Select:

[image]

Delete the "Root VC" connection, and drop a new ViewController in-between - should look about like this now:

[image]

TableView and DetailView are missing the NavBar at the top - that's OK.

Now, connect the LoginView as Nav's Root, and connect a Show segue from Login Button to TablView:

[image]

If all goes according to plan, NavBar is again showing at the top of TableView and DetailView, as desired.

Comment: That was exactly my first approach. However, while the navigation bar reappears in the UI builder, it's not displayed when I'm running the app. Also, when I tap on one of the table rows, the detail view is presented modally (from below) rather than "shown" (from the right), although the connection from the row to the detail view is still a "Show segue" connection in UI Builder, and the detail view also doesn't have a navigation bar.

Comment: Then it sounds like you're not connecting the segues right... Are you connecting with "Show" ? Or one of the other options?

Comment: When you select the segue and view Attributes Inspector, you should see "Show (e.g. Push)" if you have the right one.

Comment: Both segues (the one from the login screen to the table view, and the one from the table view to the detail view) are of the "Show (e.g. Push)" kind. I don't have an identifier for the first one because I'm not implementing the prepare(for:) method as I don't need to pass information to the UITableViewController, do you reckon I should?

Comment: Is the NavBar visible on the Login screen? If so, does TableView "slide-in-from-right" as standard with NavigationControllers?

Comment: There's space at the top of the login screen for the navbar, however it's completely empty (doesn't contain the title that I've set in the "View Controller" section of the UINavigationController). I couldn't find the setting you're mentioning in the attributes for the TableView, however the transition used to be like that (slide in from right) before I inserted the new login screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139797/discussion-between-donmag-and-david).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem
You should first add a new view and connect the navigation controller and the new view using control and trackpad. Then choose the `Root View Controller` option and that'll create a new root view and then you can choose the next screen normally. Do accordingly see the image and follow.

Select the root view controller option:
[image]

Hope this helps.